# In Google Cloud Logging, why are log messages shown out of order?

Tags: google-logging

I have a Java program running in a pod in the Google Kubernetes Environment. In GCP, there is a default logging router that routes stdout and stderr to the GCP Logging app. We have added one exclusion filter to this default router.

What I see is that sometimes (not always but regularly) log messages from a single Java process and from the same thread are listed in reverse order when their timestamp is the same (meaning that they were produced within the same millisecond).

Is there something that I can change to my Java program to prevent this from happening? Is there a field that GCP Logging uses to order messages that have the same timestamp that I am perhaps not populating?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but are both lines printed to stdout or stderr? Or is it one from both?

Comment: Nice guess but no, all the log messages are going to stdout.